# Create new entry on specific work sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a performance journal in Excel with a separate work sheet for each of my employees.  I created a cover page with a button to add the entry to a different work sheet but it only goes to that 1 sheet.  Is there a way to have the button ask which work sheet to paste the entry into.

The current coding that I have is as follows:

```
Sub AddNewEntry()

AddNewEntry Macro

    Sheets("Blank").Select
    Range("$A$6:$J$19").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
    Range("$A$6").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("$B$7:$C$7").Select

End Sub
```

I want to replace the line of code `Sheets("Sheet 1").Select` with a new line that allows me to select the sheet I want from either a combo box or a list box.

Comment: If you have a combo- or listbox already you can use a `For Each` loop to add the sheets to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok MICHAEL this should get you going.  As @jbarker2160 has commented, a combobox seems the sensible option even though you also mention a 'button'.  Assuming you have an ActiveX Combobox placed directly onto worksheet Sheet1 see below - I'll come back to your 'button' later..

In the "ThisWorkbook" module, select the "Open" event and paste-in this code:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1
    .Clear
        For Each ws In Sheets
           .AddItem ws.Name
        Next
        .Value = "Sheet1"
End With
```

This will populate the combobox when you open the workbook.

In the "Sheet1" module, select the "Worksheet" --> "Activate" event and paste-in the same code as above.  This will re-populate the combobox whenever Sheet1 is re-selected, just in case you have deleted or added new worksheets.

In the "Sheet1" module, select the  "Combobox1" --> "Change" event and paste-in the below code:

```
Dim sht As String
    If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then ComboBox1.Value = "Sheet1"
sht = ComboBox1.Value
Sheets(sht).Select
```

This will select the worksheet that you have chosen from the combobox.

You can then simply delete your `Sheets("Sheet 1").Select` line.

With your button idea, you might consider putting a button on each of your other worksheets to select Sheet1 - as a quick and easy way of getting back to the Combobox?